# runtime loading of properties in Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring

I am new to the Spring framework and trying to see if I can find a solution to runtime loading of a new Properties object on an existing PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer instance.

I started by extending Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer... and wired as follows

```
<bean class="com.myl.spring.VaultPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
 <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
 <property name="locations">
  <list>
   <value>classpath*:startup.properties</value>
  </list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

startup.properties has only one value which is a URL (i make a GET request to fetch more properties). Without this fetch, no placeholder in my context.xmls can be resolved.

Is there a way I can tell my VaultPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer during creation invoke a method to 
1st. resolve a hardcoded value -- resulting in the URL
2nd. make a GET request and load the fetched result.

Comment: We fixed that once by extending the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. We used a java.util.Timer to make the class check for changes on the .properties files every X minutes and if something was different to reload it, in your case you could use the processProperties method to load the properties you fetched from the get code. Of course this is a boilerplate solution, I honestly ignore if there is a spring implementation that accomplishes that. Also all new loaded properties would not be available during Bean creation which makes me wonder why are you trying to do that in the first place?

Comment: thanks chepech, i have no choice but implementing this way... or right now thats the only way i am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

How about loading properties in two stages. First load your startup.properties in one bean then load properties from URL resource using second bean like this:

```
<bean id="firstOrderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="order" value="100" />
  <property name="location" value="classpath*:startup.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="fromUrlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="${placeholder name from startup.properties}" />
</bean>
```

Property "order" in 1st bean will make it initialize earlier than the 2nd bean which will make url available for placeholder resolution in the 2nd bean. As an alternative to using "order" 2nd bean could be declared with depend-on="firstOrderProperties" to initialize it after 1st bean.

This solution will let you avoid the need of implementing subclass of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.